# copiar datos de un csv a un excel usando vba

Tags: excel, vba

Quiero copiar datos que tengo en un csv a un excel usando vba. Tengo el código que lo hace, pero no quiero copiar la primera fila del csv y no sé cómo hacerlo.
Este es mi csv:

[image: Mi csv]

Y este es mi código en vba de un excel:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'
' Makro1 Makro
' Makro indspillet 17-04-2017 by Cristina
'

'
Dim valuesLine
    FilePath = "C:\Users\Tmicro2\Desktop\DATOS.csv"
    Open FilePath For Input As #1
    myColumn = 1
    myRow = 2
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, valuesLine
        myarray = Split(valuesLine, ",")
        For i = 0 To UBound(myarray) - LBound(myarray)
            Hoja1.Cells(myRow, myColumn) = myarray(i)
            myColumn = myColumn + 1
        Next i
        myRow = myRow + 1
        myColumn = 1
    Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Este es el resultado que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué debo modificar del código para que no me copie los títulos de Matrícula, Grupo, Asignatura...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo haria una variable que indique en qué fila del csv estás, y si estás en la primera, saltartela:

```
myColumn = 1
myRow = 2
filaCSV = 1 ' Variable indicando el numero de fila que estamos procesando del CSV
Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, valuesLine
    if(filaCSV <> 1) then 'Si no es la primera linea, hacemos el proceso 
        myarray = Split(valuesLine, ",")
        For i = 0 To UBound(myarray) - LBound(myarray)
            Hoja1.Cells(myRow, myColumn) = myarray(i)
            myColumn = myColumn + 1
        Next i
        myRow = myRow + 1
        myColumn = 1
    end if
    filaCSV = filaCSV +1 'Sumamos 1 al numero de fila actual del CSV
Loop
```

Comment: Ya me funciona. He movido la línea "Line Input #1, valuesLine" a justo debajo del Do While y antes del If.
Muchas gracias